# Nunit: How to have an argument in NUnit attribute

Tags: c#, nunit

I am trying to call an argument with NUnit attribute I receive an error

> Invalid signature for `SetUp` or `TearDown` method: `cleanup`

My Script:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    TWebDriver driver = new TWebDriver();
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame();
    MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
    string Name = methodBase.Name;
    cleanup(Name);
}

[TearDown]
public void cleanup(string testcase)
{
    string path = (@"..\..\Passor\");
    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
    if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Failed" + ".txt"), "Failed " + testcase);
    }
    else
    {
        File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Passed" + ".txt"), "Passed " + testcase);
    }
}
```

If this is not possible. Is there any other way to add `methodname` in the cleanup method?

Comment: It's not clear why you can't you just access the Name or FullName properties of the [Test property of the TestContext](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6.4) in the cleanup method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You dont need to call `cleanup` method it will be called automatically, what you need to do is to put some property in the `TestContext` or in a field in the `class`.

For example:

#### Using a field:

```
[TestFixture]
public class GivenSomeTest
{
    private string _testCase;
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame();
        MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
        _testCase = methodBase.Name;
        TWebDriver driver = new TWebDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

    [TearDown]
    public void cleanup()
    {
        string path = (@"..\..\Passor\");
        DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Failed" + ".txt"), "Failed " + _testCase);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Passed" + ".txt"), "Passed " + _testCase);
        }
    }   
}
```

#### Using `TestContext`:

```
[TestFixture]    
public  class GivenSomeTest
{

    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        StackFrame stackFrame = new StackFrame();
        MethodBase methodBase = stackFrame.GetMethod();
        TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties.Add("testCase",methodBase.Name);
        TWebDriver driver = new TWebDriver();
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void cleanup()
    {
        var testCase = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Properties["testCase"];
        string path = (@"..\..\Passor\");
        DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        if (TestContext.CurrentContext.Result.Status == TestStatus.Failed)
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Failed" + ".txt"), "Failed " + testCase);
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(path, "Passed" + ".txt"), "Passed " + testCase);
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: It works for else condition with proper method name but it does not show me method name in my if condition

Comment: @user3338497 Just change the order, this occurs because some exception  occured before the property be setted.

Comment: @user3338497 see the answer, I change it.